# How to evaluate HTML<span sec:authentication=..> in thymleaf

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I would like to Display image on my page, I am struggling with evaluating a span tag which contains an HTTP URL.

```
 <span sec:authentication="principal.image">
```

I have Updated the Authentication Object to have custom fields like image, firstName, lastName etc. So Basically below HTML

```
<div th:fragment="logout" class="logout" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 display-label">Name:</div>
      <div class="span4 display-values">
        <p>
          <span sec:authentication="principal.firstName"></span>
          <span sec:authentication="principal.lastName"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 display-label">Email:</div>
      <div class="span4 display-values">
        <p>
          <span sec:authentication="name"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 display-label">Image:</div>
      <div class="span4 display-values">
        <span sec:authentication="principal.image"> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form action="#" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout"/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is printing

```
Name:
Abhishek 

Email:
abhishek@gmail.com

Image:
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/320426_10151045513476766_423049521_n.jpg?oh=766767548269c2483f0ad1e865d
```

As you can see I do have a valid URL I want to enclose this URL as `<img src=""...>`

I have tried

- `<img src = <span sec:authentication="principal.image"> </span></img>`
- `<img th:src = <span sec:authentication="principal.image"> </span></th>`

But none of these is working.

PS: I don't want to create a model attribute to store image URL and show it on page.

Comment: In my knowledge I think there is no other way without giving the url in src="" or th:src="".
As you don't want to show the original url in html page u can use another url which will call your controller function and provide with the inputstream so that you can preview the image without the showing the url.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you have posted is not correct.  Try using the authentication object with the following syntax:

```
<img th:if="${#authentication.principal.image}"
     th:src="${#authentication.principal.image}"
     alt="placeholder" />
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to ***why*** this is the answer.

Comment: It's really just syntax.  I updated the answer anyway.